# My custom broadcast receiver doesn't recive intents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I wrote my custom broadcast receiver to receive intents from my other app but it doesn't recieve anything. Im sure that first app is sending broadcast corectly. Can someone help me?
App1:

```
public void broadcastIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String permissions = "com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions.MY_PERMISSION";
    intent.putExtra("name", editName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("price", Float.parseFloat(editPrice.getText().toString()));
    intent.putExtra("quantity", Integer.parseInt(editQuantity.getText().toString()));
    intent.setAction("com.example.android.projekt1.notification");
    sendBroadcast(intent, permissions);
}
```

And I run this function on my setOnClickListener method.
There is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intennt received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtras(intent);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

}
So while sending broadcast I have 0 toast messages and my service doesn't run too.
There is androidManifest from receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission-group android:name="com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions"
    android:label="my permissions group"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions.MY_PERMISSION"
    android:permissionGroup="com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions"
    android:label="my permission"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions.MY_PERMISSION">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.android.projekt1.notification">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="MyService" />
</application>
```

I run my receiver first then I run my main app and press the button to send broadcast

Comment: Implicit broadcasts to manifest-registered Receivers no longer work, since API level 26. You would need to use an explicit `Intent`; i.e., one that specifically targets that Receiver class.

Comment: did you add this permission request: `<uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions.MY_PERMISSION" />` to the app that SENDS broadcast?

Comment: @BAHMAN yes, I did

Comment: Can you please set `exported="true"` in you manifest to your receiver and check?

Comment: @MayurGajra this advice didnt help me too

Answer (score 0):

set package name of targeting application:

```
public void broadcastIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String permissions = "com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver.my_permissions.MY_PERMISSION";
    intent.putExtra("name", editName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("price", Float.parseFloat(editPrice.getText().toString()));
    intent.putExtra("quantity", Integer.parseInt(editQuantity.getText().toString()));
    intent.setAction("com.example.android.projekt1.notification");
    intent.setPackage("Package name of receiver app");// set Package of targeting app
    sendBroadcast(intent, permissions);
}
```

Comment: "com.example.android.mybroadcastreceiver" - thats package name from receiver app

Comment: @masiak can you register receiver dynamically in a foreground service in receiver app instead of registering it in manifest and see if you receive broadcasts or not?